# На этапе сортировки во vue выкидывает ошибку Avoid mutating a prop directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
  <select v-model="modelValue" @change="changeOptions">

    <option disabled>Выбурите из списка</option>
    <option v-for = "option in options" v-bind:key="option.value" :value="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "my-select",

  props:{
    modelValue: {
      type: String,


    },
    options:{
      type: Array,
      default: ()=> []
    },

  },    
  methods:{
    changeOptions(event) {    
      this.$emit("modelValue", event.target.value)        
    }
  }
}        
</script>

<style scoped>   
</style>
```

Текст ошибки:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
> whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
> computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
> "modelValue"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: А где ошибка? Или предлагаешь пересматривать обучающее видео? ))

Comment: Извиняюсь. Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "modelValue"

Comment: @Александр Так прочитайте просто, что написано в ошибке. Вам же прямо говорят, что Вы изменяете `modelValue`, который является `prop`, а всё что prop - изменять нельзя.

Comment: Vladimir Gonchar. Если бы ты не сказал я и не знал... Если не чего по коду сказать лучше помолчи

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html
Добавьте опцию model.

```
model: {
    prop: 'modelValue',
    event: 'change'
}
```

Comment: Спасибо но не работает